# Access data in multiple tabs - datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery datatable . Table is inside a form.When i submit the form i can only access to the data on the tab which is currently opened . data in other tabs are not submitted. 
 this is how i initialize the data table

```
<script defer>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tbl_location').dataTable({
            "bSort": false
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to access the data in all tabs. I tried to find this issue in their forum but i didn't see anything related to this topic.I would be glad if anyone can give me an idea.

Comment: you can take your grid outside your tab

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
('#form').submit( function() {
          var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(false); //get all datatables
          var list = Array()
           $.each(table, function(key, value) {               
              list.push($(value).dataTable().fnGetData())
          });               
            $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', "tablesdata")
            .attr('value',  list)
            .appendTo('#form');
            return true;
        } );
    });
```

Hope it'll be helpful